# Problems displaying a table on mobile version of my site

Tags: css, mobile

I've been trying to fix this issue for 10 days now and still i couldn't find any solution.

I have a table that shows perfectly on desktop version but on mobile it gets out of the page area, i tried also @media screen max width 600px to modify the size of the table and overflow hidden but still not working, i will paste the code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #0288D1;
        border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: large;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#0277BD"><strong>Some Text Here<strong></th></tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>Some Text Here</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Some Text Here</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Some Text Here</strong></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://somesite.com/play"><img width="200" height="80" src="https://somesite.com/image.png" alt="Some Text Here"></a>
            </td>

            <td><strong><font color="green">Some Text Here</font></strong></td>
            <td>Some Text Here</td>

            <td>
                <div>
                    <button class="playblock" style="display:block;width:150px;height:50px;background-color:#4CAF50;margin-bottom:5px;color:white;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='green'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#4CAF50'" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://somesitehere.com/play';">PLAY</button>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button class="reviewblock" style="display:block;width:150px;height:50px;background-color:#EB9C12;color:white;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='orange'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#EB9C12'" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://somesitehere.com/see/';">REVIEW</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: where are the media queries you tried? Also you dont close your table and tbody tags

Comment: They are closed but somehow from the paste those 2 lines missed : </tbody>
</table>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all your feedback.

I fixed it myself after some testing using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with tables on mobile. It is not clear if you are using the table for layout or if you will have more rows of data with `Play` and `Review` links.

1. If you are using it for layout, I would suggest exploring a `flexbox` layout instead.
2. If you are planning to have more rows in the table you could wrap the table in a `<div>` with `max-width: 100%; overflow: auto;` that would allow the div/table to horizontally scroll but not otherwise affect the layout of the page. Pair this with reduced font-size on smaller screens and, IMO, you get a pretty usable table on mobile.
3. There are a few methods for modifying how a table is rendered on small screens by using a data attribute (like `data-title`) on the `<td>` and `<th>` that duplicate the column heading so that on small screens you can pull the data attribute using a `::before` pseudo element like `td::before { content: attr(data-title); }` and tell your table elements to all be `display: block;` and styling them kinda like each row is it's own table.
   Here is an example from CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Hi, i will not have more rows with Play and Review, they are just 2 buttons one on top of each other in a div.

Comment: I agree here, try to get away from the table idea.  Use divs instead.

Comment: i tried with divs but it looked worst so i came back to the table idea...

Comment: Definitely avoid tables for layout, tables are mainly for showing tabular data.

Comment: Can you give me a div table responsive example please? That will show nice on mobile also

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what it should look like on mobile. The simple fix is to set a min-width on the table but this might make things to small on mobile. You should also be using a media query to make the buttons smaller, they are very large.

```
table { min-width: 500px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a container element with `overflow-x:auto` around the `<table>`, for example:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
     <table>
         ...
     </table>
</div>
```

This table will display a horizontal scroll bar if the screen is too small to display the full content.